# Multithreaded item-processing queue

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net, thread-safety, queue

I have this `Queue` declared in my class:

```
static private Queue<SignerDocument> QUEUE = new Queue<SignerDocument>();
```

I fill this `Queue` with some items to process, and I want to process it using multithreading.

Did I need to use lock in this case, to ensure that `QUEUE.Dequeue` is thread-safe?

```
static protected void ThreadProcManager()
{     
   lock (typeof(Queue<SignerDocument>))
   {
       if (QUEUE.Count > 0)
       {
           ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc, QUEUE.Dequeue());
        }
    }
}

 static private void ThreadProc(Object stateInfo)
 {
     //Do the work...
 }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a queue object to buffer work items for ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (which is itself a queue)?  The most intuitive behavior would be to perform the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem call immediately where you would currently be doing a QUEUE.Enqueue call.  If for some reason you do need this batching behavior, you really need to write a wrapper class for Queue which locks all access calls, such as Count, Peek, Enqueue, Dequeue, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and don't lock on `typeof` - [highly unrecommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1603044/3312). Also you'll need to lock whatever's adding to the `QUEUE` so that the multithreaded `Dequeue()` does not race against it.

```
static protected void ThreadProcManager()
{     
   lock (QUEUE)
   {
       if (QUEUE.Count > 0)
       {
           ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc, QUEUE.Dequeue());
        }
    }
}

 static private void ThreadProc(Object stateInfo)
 {
     //Do the work...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Queue.Dequeue()` is not threadsafe, so you need to lock it if it's called from multiple threads.

However, there's not enough information here to say for sure whether a lock is required in this particular case. The call to `QUEUE.Dequeue()` is not done from a ThreadPool worker, it's done in the `ThreadProcManager()` function. So the question is really whether you call ThreadProcManager(), or any of the other methods on `QUEUE`, from multiple threads.